# Fedora 20 Gnome upgrade - cannot login anymore

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

I started to use Fedora with with Gnome 2x. I started to upgrade to gnome 3x when I had some eletric energy problem in my build and my machine turned off. Now I cannot log in any more - meggage "Oh No! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occured and the system can't recover. All extensions have been disabled"

If I try to run 'yum update' again there is two strange things

1) Error: Package: PackageKit-yum-plugin-0.8.17.1.fc20.x86_64 Required: Package(x86-64) = 0.8.17-1.fc20 Installed: PackageKit-0.8.13-1.fc20.x68_64

2) Lots of "Package [example] is a duplicate with [example]"

Please cold someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below command and remove the genome3x,

rm -rf ~/.gnome3

rm -rf ~/.gconf

rm -rf ~/.gconfd

logged out/in

After removing try with upgradation if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Your system crashed before it managed to cleanup the old packages (after installing newer ones) - hence the messages.

You can fix this by removing the older one.

Check exactly which versions you have installed.  For example, if `[example]` in your question is `gnutls`, then:

```
yum list installed gnutls
```

It should show:

```
Installed Packages
gnutls.x86_64                 3.1.18-10.el7_0                    installed
gnutls.x86_64                 3.1.18-11.el7_0                    installed
```

You need to remove one of the packages - preferably the earliest one:

```
yum remove gnutls-3.1.18-10.el7_0
```

Repeat with all the duplicates.

Please note that the example above was from a CentOS 7 system, so yours will be slightly different.

Comment: Is there any way to delete all packages from a specific repository?

Comment: There's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500454/how-to-remove-all-packages-from-specific-repo-without-dependencies), but I'd be very weary of doing this - if you accidentally remove the wrong package, your system will be borked.  Also, it may not work until you resolve your current issues anyway.

Comment: I got it but I identified that all duplicate packeges has the same @ anaconda. Is there anyway to use this label to delete all @ anaconda packages?

Comment: the problem is that there are more then 100 packages to delete manually

Comment: But not all `@anaconda` packages are duplicates.  If you were to delete all of them, you may find that you'd delete an important package and bork your system. You may be able to use some text manipulation to convert the output to a list and then pipe that list into `yum remove`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try `yum-complete-transaction`. It's possible that this will just finish everything up.

If it doesn't, try `package-cleanup` from the `yum-utils` package.

```
$ sudo yum install yum-utils   # if you don't have it already
...
$ package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

If you're lucky, that will do it. If you're less lucky, you may need to do some manual cleanup, package by package. After running that, do `package-cleanup --problems` to find other yum/rpm db issues, and then do one more `yum update`.

If after getting your yum/rpm situation into line, things still don't work, try creating a brand new clean user to see if that user can log in. If it can, but yours can't, cleaning up the config files in your own home directory may help.

And if none of that works -- well, this kind of thing is why we have backups. Maybe it's nature's way of saying that it's time to install the Fedora 21 beta. (Disclaimer: I work on Fedora.)